# HTML bootstrap footer is not responding as it should. It is not sticking at the bottom and also not showing 100% width as I have programmed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

I am making a small Sinatra app and using bootstrap for layout. But it is giving some issues.

It is not sticking at the bottom and also not showing 100% width as I have programmed. Also, the text of the footer is not getting centralized after even trying the text-center class.

Below is my HTML for the footer.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
     <footer id="footer">
       <p class="mx-auto">&copy; 2017 <strong>Coding Tips</strong></p>
     </footer>
</div>
```

Please also see below my CSS for the footer.

```
#footer {
  background-color: white;
  color: #111111;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /*height: 20px;*/
  align-content: center;
}
```

Any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: See this example of a sticky footer, by bootstrap. http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/

Comment: This is not a Bootstrap problem. Using relative positioning and `bottom: 0;` will not make the element stick to the bottom of the parent. Why? Relative positioned elements are moved relative to their position in the document. This re-positioning is a visual trick as the element continues to take up the same space in the document flow that it had prior to relative positioning. With just your code and Bootstrap's, your element is 100% width of parent. You must have something else intervening.

Answer (score 0):

There's a much easier way to create a sticky Bootstrap footer that doesn't require you to write any styles yourself. The Bootstrap navigation bar component comes with the `.navbar-fixed-bottom` class, alowing you to fix a navbar to the bottom of the screen. For an example,

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <p>&copy; 2017 <strong>Coding Tips</strong></p>
  </div>
</nav>
```

With this, you can get a fixed-to-bottom navigation bar that acts as a footer using pure Bootstrap.

### Edit - Creating a sticky footer that expands with the page.

The previous example demonstrates how to create a footer that is fixed to the bottom of the viewport, superimposed over the page content. If you're looking for a footer that will only be fixed to the bottom of the screen when content is sparse, we can use flexible boxes.

```css
body {
  margin: 0; /* To ensure the footer takes up the full width of the viewport */
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    Your content goes here.
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p>&copy; 2017 <strong>Coding Tips</strong></p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

The `.content` class automatically takes up the available space, forcing the footer to the bottom of the screen. Since we set the minimum height of `.container` to `100vh`, it'll take up at least the entire height of the screen. Once more space is needed, the footer get's pushed down further. Flexbox provides what's probably the easiest and cleanest method of achieving this effect.

Bootstrap navbars: [Components - Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)
Solved by Flexbox: [Sticky Footer - Solved by Flexbox - Cleaner, hack-free CSS](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/)

Comment: Note, this is not a typical _sticky footer_. Usually  a sticky footer will expand with the content of the page and be placed after it. This solution places the footer element at the bottom of the viewport and remains their, overlaying content.

Comment: @hungerstar Are you thinking of something along the lines of [this](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/)?

Comment: Yes, that is one possible solution. There are others but flexbox is the cleanest and most flexible.

Comment: Hi, @natejms thanks a lot for the help. It does make my text in the center but doesn't still give background 100% width!

Comment: @HimaChhag Hmm... See if any of your parent elements to the footer have padding or margins. If you can't figure out which one (and it's not the body tag), then use the "Computed" tab in your browser's Inspect Elements menu.

Answer (score -1):

to align text in center please use

```
 text-align: center;
```

the width is 100% as needed and
to place footer  at the bottom you can give
     `top: 400px;` 
please check the given link https://jsfiddle.net/komal10041992/xn8mmg44/3/

Comment: Adding a fixed value to `top` is a poor, inflexible approach to getting a footer to stick to the bottom of a page.